# repaint() in loop only called once - Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to draw a grid on a JPanel but when I call the repaint method inside a loop it works only once. Here is my code:

```
public class Board extends JPanel{

    // --- Set Density of Grid ---
    public final int lines = 10;
    // ---------------------------

    public final int width =  600;
    public final int height = 600;

    public Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
    public Point p2 = new Point(0,0);

    public Board() {


        int c0 = width/lines;
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            int c1 = width/lines;
            for (int i=0; i<lines; i++){

                if (j==0){
                    p1 = new Point(c1,0);
                    p2 = new Point(c1,height);
                }

                if (j==1){
                    p1 = new Point(0,c1);
                    p2 = new Point(width,c1);
                }

                c1 = c1 + c0;

                repaint();

            }
        }
    }


    public void drawGrid(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawGrid(g);
        System.out.println("Inside");
    }

}
```

this is the output:

```
Inside
```

How can I call the paintComponent method multiple times when I use for loop?

Comment: I think we are missing something here. I don't see the paintComponent() method being called anywhere here. Could you provide us with some more code?

Comment: paintComponet() can't be called. You can only use repaint()

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344431/repaint-is-not-being-called-in-java-while-loop). Maybe that will help you.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense you would have this loop inside your constructor as long as you don't want to do an animation. You only create 2 accessible points, the `paintComponent` method would only draw a line between the last 2. Just handle all the drawing inside the `drawGrid` or `paintComponent` method (and create points there).

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thanks, that helped

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
 and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `repaint()` method just makes a request to the `RepaintManager` to paint components. The `RepaintManager` will then consolidate multiple requests into a single painting of the component to make the painting more efficient. So because all your requests are made within nanoseconds of one another in your loop, they all get consolidated into a single request.

If you want animation of some kind then you need to use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation. So each time the Timer fires you would increment the indexes by one.

Comment: I tried use Tread.sleep() inside the for loop, but it didn't change anything

Comment: @dirac See the last paragraph of the answer. You can't use `Thread.sleep` in this context, you have to use a Swing `Timer`